# How do bodies moving relative to each other measure light the same?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, observers

I am not a pysicist, just an amateur, so this might be a simple question but it has me stumped. I have dug the internet for some type of answer but can't find any so I decided to ask here.

Suppose you had two bodies (A and B) moving at a given speed (v) towards one another, then a beam of light goes by in the same direction as A (relative to B; in the direction directly opposite B's movement from A's perspective). Both bodies should measure the speed of that beam the same, because speed of light is constant relative to any inertial frame. However, both will measure it having moved more in relation to B than to A. What stumps me is, from the frame of each body, the other is moving towards them at speed v, so time dilation should work both ways the same (A will think B's time is slower and B will think A's time is slower). How then can light have moved "faster" in relation to B than to A from both their perspectives? That is, how could both bodies "agree" that the beam has moved a greater distance in relation to B than to A but "disagree" on how time is passing in relation to each other? Wouldn't that imply that one of the inertial frames measures light differently from the other?

Comment: The key to this paradox is the relativity of simultaneity.  Look at a spacetime diagram, and see how the "distance between the ships" is different between "A"'s frame, and "B's frame as percieved by A"

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember is that time is just a coordinate, like x, y, and z. Consider two people standing facing each other at a train station. One says "London is 10 km ahead of us". The other says "No, London is 10 km behind us". There is no contradiction, because both are using different coordinate systems. Similarly, two people in relative motion might each claim that less time has passed for the other. There is no contradiction, because the two are using different coordinate systems (different directions for time).

In fact having different directions for time is exactly what it means for people to be moving relative to each other. If a clock is moving relative to me, than each tick of the second hand on the clock not only takes up time relative to me, but it also takes up space (the clock has moved during the tick). So the clock's notion of the time direction is, in my coordinate system, mixed up with a space direction.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jerry Schirmer (hi Jerry, +1) there is a graphical tool used to solve special relativity problems just like this called a *spacetime diagram*. It takes most of the puzzlement and confusion out of the solution process and is not too difficult to learn. This is probably not the best place for a tutorial but if you search on that term you'll find lots of examples on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Light has no rest frame, so we can just make any coordinate system ($S$) and center it on the emission event $E_0$. In one spatial dimension that will have coordinates $(t, x)$:

$$E_0=(0,0)$$

If it travels $L$ in the $x$ direction, it will be detected at the event:

$$E_1=(\frac L c,L) $$

so the observed velocity is:

$$ v = \frac{x_1-x_0}{t_1-t_0} = \frac{L}{L/c}=c$$

as it must.

In a moving frame, $S'$, which moves at $\beta\times c$, those events transform to:

$$E_0'=(0,0)$$

and

$$E_1'=\big(\gamma(t_1-\beta x_1/c), \gamma(x_1-\beta ct_1)\big)$$
$$E_1'=\big(\gamma(L/c-\beta L/c), \gamma(L-\beta L)\big)$$
$$E_1'=\big(\gamma(1-\beta)L/c, \gamma(1-\beta)L\big)$$
$$E_1'=(L'/c, L')$$

with $L'=\gamma(1-\beta)L$.

Clearly:

$$ v' = \frac{x'_1-x'_0}{t'_1-t'_0} = \frac{L'}{L'/c}=c$$

Getting $c$ back was no big deal. The answer to your question appears in the ratio of the observed interval (spatial or temporal) between emission and detection:

$$ R(\beta)\equiv \frac{L'}{L} = \gamma(1-\beta)$$

Your complaint was that it must be true that:

$$R(\beta)\ne R(-\beta)$$

but how can that be if:

$$ \gamma(\pm \beta)\equiv \frac 1{\sqrt{1-[\pm\beta]^2}} = \gamma(\mp \beta)$$

i.e.,  time-dilation is symmetric w.r.t. to velocity direction.

There is another additive term that is linear in $\beta$ due to the relativity of simultaneity.  (Note: this term is what resolves the standard special relativity paradoxes caused by $\gamma$ acting alone as a time dilator/length contractor).

That's the (linear) math of it. A slope (time dilation/length contraction) and an intercept (simultaneity). Check it out on a Minkowski diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that, since speed is distance divided by time, if A and B disagree on how far the beam of light has moved, then they will also disagree on when the light beam's journey started and/or ended. The disagreements about the time that has elapsed when light move between the two points are such that they cancel out the disagreements about the distance between the two points, so that both observers still arrive at the same result for the speed of light.